# Changing PDO::FECH_ASSOC into string

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use a function to get the password of the user based on the username that is entered. However I can not seem to get the result to be a string. How to i transfer it to a string? I just want the value that is stored in the `password` column.

here is the function

```
public function get_password($username) {
    global $pdo;

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $username);
    $query->execute();

    $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $query;
}
```

i want this because i keep getting a error saying that a parameter that uses the result from this function expects string, array given, so i assume the result from the function needs to be a string not an array

EDIT: I tried adding `$query['password']` but it returned an error that said `Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array`

Comment: return $query["password"];

Comment: @Al. if i do that i get this error `Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array`

Comment: `fetch` ***returns*** the data, it does not *change* `$query` into data.

Comment: OK, sorry I was lazy, let me post a fix, be 2 mins. I see I am too slow :) BTW its not good practice to store plain text passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
public function get_password($username) {
    global $pdo;

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $username);
    $query->execute();

    $password = "";
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $password = $row['password'];
    }
    return $password;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $password = $row['password'];
}
```